# ROS instalation - broken packages

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I am trying to install ros noetic following [ros wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu) tutorial. When i try to `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full` an error ocurres.

```
samet@samet-X540LA:~$ sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-noetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-noetic-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-noetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-noetic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using ubuntu 20.04

I tried installing with `aptitude`. Packages installed. But when i write `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash` i see

```
samet@samet-X540LA:~$ source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
bash: /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

And no `ros` folder in `/opt`

Comment: have you already tried after doing another `sudo apt update`?

Comment: @ChristianFritz yes i tried

Comment: "you have held broken packages" usually means you need to first resolve issues using `sudo apt install -f` (without any more arguments). I would try that and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem via `aptitude`

```
sudo aptitude install ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

`aptitude` gave me several solutions. First and second solutions didn't work, but the third solution worked and i can use ros.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo apt remove ros-noetic-*
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt upgrade -y
udo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full -y
```

this does:

1. Removes broken packages.
2. Installs if any packages requires.
3. Finally installs noetic version of ROS.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I tried your instructions but it didn't work. I'm getting same error.